# Как загрузить файл в форме без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

Форма, вписываем данные, кнопка отправить - все работает. Хочу добавить `input`, в котором можно выбрать файлик для загрузки. Да да, в интернете полно примеров, но спрошу кое что нестандартное. Хочется вписать в `input` только адрес файла (сам файл мы не загружаем). И после вписывания адреса (т.е. если заполнено) охота чуть ниже сделать еще один `input` (до 7-10ми штук). ( Ест-но без перезагрузки страницы. )

Уважаемые, подскажите, как это реализовать?

p.s. собственно вот уже в форме куда передаю там уже и буду думать как файл загрузить, и буду рад подсказкам

p.p.s. iframe - прошу, не предлагайте.

добавлено спустя 2 часа:

```
// подключаем JQ
// ждем нажатия ссылки у id=text1
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "if.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: id},
            success: function(text) {
                $("#text1").append(text);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

// в место инпута пишу это
<div id="text1">
<a href="#" id="1">Добавить</a>
</div>

// создаем if.php - здесь будем добавлять input'ы для файлов
// и на этом я остановился
// echo "1"; // при нажатии на ссылку выше - просто добавляются единицы без перезагрузки
```

спустя 5 часов:
**Вообщем**, критику я воспринимаю адекватно, и буду рад решению. если не найду, выложу свое решение. Пусть не идеальное, но оно оптимизированное, которое можно подстроить под себя (а именно это самый главный минус примеров из инета)

Comment: Ну, добавить пару-надцать полей - не проблема. И зачем "*думать как файл загрузить*", если их можно спокойно загрузить через скрытый iframe? Или, как говориться, мы не ищем лёгких путей?

Comment: [всё уже написано до вас](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Comment: Deonis, я плохо знаю AJAX, вот по этому и спросил. Spectre,  привес няшности и наглядности приведенного в пример решения - мне хотелось чуть поправить свое, а сейчас, смотря пример, думаю как из 250кб кода достать нужный 1кб 8-(

Comment: Да, сложно когда Dial-Up... Борешься за каждый кб. ))) Самое интересное, что уменьшив код на десяток кб. и радуясь, потирая ручки, совершенно не обращаешь вниамния на то, что графика, по сравнению со скриптами, в десятки раз тяжелее ;) 

А по сути - то ajax вам знать и не надо, т.к. ajax не поддерживает загрузку файлов. Точнее технология есть - "**XMLHttpRequest 2**", но вот бяда: на сегодняшний день, её поддерживает один Chrome, да и то с глюками.

Comment: Да, особенно если учесть что у мобильных устройств скорость Dial-UP, приходится учитывать не свои хотелки, а так сказать пользовательские. Да и к сожалению внешний вид приведенного выше решения поправить будет сложнее и дольше, чем если написать с нуля

Comment: @mixalef, вот тю... Так чего вы хотите? я так и не могу понять? Если пользователь хочет загружать со своего устройства, то зачем **input type="file"** заменять чем-то другим? Он замечательно [справляется со своей работой](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/puUCW/), но без загрузки на сервер, вы ничего с ним не сделаете. Если же файл загружается по внешней ссылке, то тем более не надо ничего менять, а использовать **input type="text"**. И в первом случае, я уже повторюсь, что вам придётся обходиться без **ajax**!

Comment: мне бы хотя бы какой то рабочий код (JS, JQ), а не решение по ссылке выше, которое во первых не подходит, во вторых страшно тормозит. хочется встроить код в свой, а не свой натягивать на чужое, т.к. своего оч. много. к тому же указал, что input'оф охота несколько

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если просто вписать путь к файлу в файловой системе ничего не получится. Ни какой скрипт, браузер или сервер (если передать ему путь) не сможет получить доступ к файлу. Это сделано в целях безопасности. Пользователь должен сам, вручную, выбрать файл в диалоговом окне. Это стандарт. Представьте что бы было если бы сайты сами могли бы копировать файлы с вашего компа.